# Neural Network for Reverberation Decay Rate Prediction (Keras)

Tags: machine-learning, python

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this question, sorry if it's not.

Essentialy I’m trying to use a neural network to predict decay rate from a reverberant audio sample. I have taken a single word utterance, and used a simple convolution reverb to create 10,000 examples with decay rates of 0 to 10. This has been done twice, so I have a second 10,000 example dataset for testing.  There are 20 inputs to the neural network, corresponding to the points in the FFT of the envelope of the reverberant sample with frequency <20Hz. The 20 features have all been standardised using my own code (in both datasets). The neural network has 1 hidden layer with 10 neurons, and 1 neuron on the output layer, with a loss factor of mean absolute error and an RMSProp optimiser. The activation function for the output neuron is linear. I have tried several different activation functions for the rest. I am not getting good results, which I think I really should be for such a simple problem – this set of graphs of the inputs clearly shows that. Anyone know why I’m getting these results and what I could do to get the network working?

Graphs of inputs to neural network (features):
[image]

Prediction results on unseen dataset for different activation functions, same hyperparameters:
[image]

Dataset generation:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

"""Read wav file and append zeros to end for 'space' for reverb"""
rate, wave = wav.read('ting.wav')
pad = np.zeros(len(wave)*5)
wave = np.append(wave, pad)

"""create gaussian white noise of duration equal to padded wav"""
dur = len(wave)/rate
noise = rdm.normal(loc=0, scale=5000, size=len(wave))
b = np.linspace(0, dur, len(noise))

"""Create decay curve, multiply with noise and convolve the result with
   the wav for reverberated samples"""
n = 10000
data = np.empty([n, len(noise)])
dec = np.empty(n)
for i in range(0,n):
    dec[i] = 10 * rdm.ranf()
    env = np.exp(-b*dec[i])
    rev = np.multiply(noise, env)
    revfft = np.fft.fft(rev)
    wavefft = np.fft.fft(wave)
    data[i, :] = np.fft.ifft(np.multiply(revfft, wavefft))

"""Define a low-pass filter"""
def butter_lowpass(dat, cutoff, rate, order=4):
    nyq = 0.5*rate
    norm_cutoff = cutoff/nyq
    b, a = sig.butter(order, norm_cutoff)
    passed = sig.lfilter(b, a, dat)
    return passed

"""Take the envelope of the reverberated sample, low-pass it, then take the
   FFT. Take FFT results for frequencies < 20Hz and average them into 20 
   features for input to the neural network"""
import pandas as pd
import scipy.signal as sig
X = np.empty([len(data), 20])
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    hil = abs(sig.hilbert(data[i, :]))
    passed = butter_lowpass(hil, 50, rate, 4)
    lf = np.fft.fft(passed)
    freq = np.fft.fftfreq(lf.size, 1/rate)
    lf = lf[np.where(freq<20)]
    freq = freq[np.where(freq<20)]
    lf = lf[np.where(freq>0)]
    lf = pd.rolling_mean(lf, len(lf)-19)
    lf = lf[~np.isnan(lf)]
    X[i,:] = lf 

np.save('X2_new2', X)
np.save('dec2_new2', dec)
```

Neural Network and prediction:

```
import numpy as np

"""Load training dataset"""
X = np.load('X_new2.npy')
dec = np.load('dec_new2.npy')

"""Define standardisation function and standardise features"""
def standardise(X):
    for i in range(0, len(X[0, :])):
        mean = np.mean(X[:, i])
        sd = np.std(X[:, i])
        for j in range(0, len(X[:, 0])):
            X[j, i] = (X[j, i] - mean)/sd
    return X
X = standardise(X)

"""Define and fit neural network"""
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim=20, output_dim=10))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.add(Dense(input_dim=10, output_dim=1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
rmsprop = RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-6)
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error',
              optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(X, dec, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=1)

"""Load test dataset, standardise and predict decay rates"""
X2 = np.load('X2_new2.npy')
dec2 = np.load('dec2_new2.npy')
dec2 = dec2.reshape(-1, 1)
X2 = standardise(X2)
pred = model.predict(X2)

"""Plot results"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(dec2, pred, label='linear')
plt.plot(range(0,11),range(0,11))
plt.xlabel('True Decay Rate')
plt.ylabel('Predicted Decay Rate')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```